# How can the timeout value of an NSMutableURLRequest be set in XCode?

Tags: xcode

I'm setting the timeout value of an NSMutableURLRequest in code as follows:

```
request.timeoutInterval = 30.0;
```

I'd like to be able to change this value during runtime while debugging, so tried this in the console (its for lldb):

```
expr request.timeoutInterval = 0.1
```

but that gives:

```
error: property 'timeoutInterval' not found on object of type 'NSMutableURLRequest *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

So I tried this:

expr [request setTimeoutInterval: 30.0]

But that generated:

error: no known method '-setTimeoutInterval:'; cast the message send to the method's return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression

Anybody got any ideas how to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
expr (NSMutableURLRequest)[request setTimeoutInterval:0.1]
```

Should work better :)

Comment: Thanks, actually it needs to be expr (NSMutableURLRequest*)[request setTimeoutInterval:0.1]

Comment: Oups, don't know how I messed up this pasting :)